# Why does perspective changes fixed position in CSS?

Tags: html, css

In the example of http://jsfiddle.net/sqk3k2nq/ , the elements are set to be `fixed` at the same position.

HTML:

```
<div>
    <span>This is A</span>
    <div>
        <span>This is B</span>
        <div>
            <span>This is C</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div {
    border: 1px solid red;
    position: fixed;
    top: 20px;
    left: 20px;
}
```

However, if we add `perspective: 1000px;` to `div`, the position will look like `relative` instead of `fixed`. See http://jsfiddle.net/sqk3k2nq/1/

Why setting `perspective` changes it to be `relative`?
For some reason, I have to set `perspective` to it and I wish `A`, `B`, and `C` can still be in the same position. Is it possible?

Comment: just guessing, but could you use `z-index`?

Comment: @MrCoder How exactly?

Comment: z-index doesn't seem to do much in this context.

Comment: @RobertHarvey what happened to your answer? Was working fine for me in chrome?

Comment: @MrCoder: It's not a 3D element in the fiddle.  I'm not convinced that it works at all.  I think Fiddle is just ignoring it.

Comment: @ Ovilia what will happen if you remove the top and left properties, like this  http://jsfiddle.net/afk2uext/1/

Comment: @MrCoder He just took `-webkit-perspective` to be `webkit-perspective`.

Comment: No, I added the dash.

Comment: @RobertHarvey With the dash, it's the same with `perspective` in Chrome 37. So this is not the cause.

Comment: I fell this is wayyyyyy above my talents here. :(

Answer (score 20):

> Why does perspective changes fixed position in CSS?

Because `perspective` establishes a containing block similar to the way `position: relative;` does, which is stated in the [transform module](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transforms/#perspective-property):

> **Perspective**
>
> The use of this property with any value other than none establishes a
> stacking context. It also establishes a containing block (somewhat
> similar to position: relative), just like the transform property does.

Since you're applying a perspective to every div in your example (and top, left properties) each div creates its own containing block and ends up pushed 20px to the right and bottom of the previous div.

Comment: Sounds convincing. But what can I do about it? Even if I set `perspective` only to the parent, it will look like http://jsfiddle.net/sqk3k2nq/2/ . Is there any chance that `A`, `B`, `C` be at the same position and they are all `fixed`?

Comment: I don't think it's possible (without making significant changes to your CSS).