# Sticky Navbar not working with Perspective css Property in Paralax Scrolling

Tags: javascript, css, navbar, parallax, sticky

I figured out that the Perspective CSS property I have listed in my div for a parallax scrolling is causing my sticky navbar function to not work at all.

Does anyone have suggestions?

Here's a link to my code: https://jsbin.com/luresosone/edit?html,css,js,output

```js
$('.navbar').affix({
  offset: {
    top: function() {
      return (this.top = $('.navbar').offset().top)
    }
  }
});
```

```css
@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .carousel-caption {
    display: none;
  }
  .navbar {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
  }
  .row.content {
    height: 450px
  }
  .sidenav {
    padding-top: 20px;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    height: 100%;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .sidenav {
    height: auto;
    padding: 15px;
  }
  .row.content {
    height: auto;
  }
}

.panel-footer.panel-custom {
  background: red;
  color: white;
}

.navbar.navbar-default.affix {
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.jumbotron {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}


/* Parllax scrolling styling starts */

.parallax {
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-x: auto;
  /* I believe this is causing the issue */
  -webkit-perspective: 300px;
  perspective: 300px;
  /* I believe this is causing the issue */
}

.parallax__group {
  position: relative;
  height: 500px;
  height: 100vh;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.parallax__layer {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.parallax__layer--fore {
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(90px) scale(.7);
  transform: translateZ(90px) scale(.7);
  z-index: 1;
}

.title {
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

#group1 {
  z-index: 5;
  /* Slide over group 2 */
  background-color: transparent
}

#group1 .parallax__layer--base {
  background: red;
  height: 65%
}

#group1 .parallax__layer--fore {
  background: yellow left:27%;
  top: 20%
}

#group2 {
  z-index: 3;
  /* Slide under groups 1 and 3 */
}

#group2 .parallax__layer--back {
  background: green;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 616px;
  padding-top: 140px;
  padding-bottom: 140px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />

  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="parallax">
    <div class="jumbotron">
      <div class="container text-center">
        <p>fdsfdsfsdfdsfsd</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">sadsadasd</a>
        </div>

        <div id="myNavbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">hgfgfsf</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">dsasafew</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">dsadsaf</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">dsadasd</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Cdas</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <div id="group1" class="parallax__group">
      <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer--base"></div>
      <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer--fore"></div>
    </div>

    <div id="group2" class="parallax__group">
      <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer--back"></div>
    </div>
    <p style="font-size: 20px">Some code to waste space to make the sticky navbar work</p>
    <p style="font-size: 20px">Some code to waste space to make the sticky navbar work</p>
    <p style="font-size: 20px">Some code to waste space to make the sticky navbar work</p>
    <p style="font-size: 20px">Some code to waste space to make the sticky navbar work</p>
    <p style="font-size: 20px">Some code to waste space to make the sticky navbar work</p>
    <p style="font-size: 20px">Some code to waste space to make the sticky navbar work</p>
    <p style="font-size: 20px">Some code to waste space to make the sticky navbar work</p>
    <p style="font-size: 20px">Some code to waste space to make the sticky navbar work</p>
    <p style="font-size: 20px">Some code to waste space to make the sticky navbar work</p>
    <p style="font-size: 20px">Some code to waste space to make the sticky navbar work</p>
    <p style="font-size: 20px">Some code to waste space to make the sticky navbar work</p>
    <p style="font-size: 20px">Some code to waste space to make the sticky navbar work</p>
    <p style="font-size: 20px">Some code to waste space to make the sticky navbar work</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you keep `navbar` outside of `parallax`? This will solve your problem. [**Reference**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26386356/3239951)

**[Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/kxk0Lw1t/1/)**

Comment: Thanks for the reply, the reason the navbar isnt outside the parallax, is because the parallax div has an overflow-x:auto, thus the navbar then creates a separate window above the parallax div, if i take the overflow-x out, it works, but then i dont have the effect of the parallax scrolling anymore.

Comment: How can `overflow-x:auto` help you have parallax scrolling effects? I don't understand.

Comment: please see this link to a demo of an example, http://keithclark.co.uk/articles/pure-css-parallax-websites/demo3/ the main Parallax div has an overflow-x and y, without it, this particular way of advanced parallax scrolling, doesnt work, its using several layers ontop of one another, to create the illusion that each layer is moving separately, its not just having layers scroll over one another.

Comment: If you see your reference link `.parallax` is `overflow-x: hidden;`

Comment: so are you saying it should be hidden and not Auto? doesnt change anything, the issue is with the .parallax_group div                            -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
transform-style: preserve-3d;

Comment: think you are miss understanding me, please see updated file, i have added images to give the effect, i wanted to avoid using images, so as you can see, the images move slower than the coloured slides over the image slides, so that works fine, but now the navbar isnt working, the navar is suppose to be sticky, i you take the overflow out, the whole effect of the parallax is gone. https://jsfiddle.net/kxk0Lw1t/3/