# position: fixed does not work in Chrome & Firebox due to perspective attribute

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I am trying to keep a div object fixed in the window independent of the user scrolling position.

I thought that is done with the

```
position: fixed
```

attribute, but in Chrome and Firefox this does not seem to work in my case, while in Safari it does?
I tracked down the issue to a

```
perspective: 1500px
```

attribute which I give to one of the parent div's. I created a simplified snipped below, which demonstrates the problem.

If you go to the css and remove the perspective attribute from navbar_wrapper the red box does indeed stay fixed. Note that in Safari it works all the time, while in Chrome & Firefox it only works after removing the perspective element. Any idea what is going on here?

```css
#navbar_wrapper {
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
  perspective: 1500px;
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  padding: 50px 0 0 0;
  min-height: 100%;
}

#basket {
  position: fixed;
  max-width: 20%;
  left: 80%;
  top: 60px;
}
```

```html
<div id="navbar_wrapper">

  <div id="product_basket">
    <div id="basket" style="background:red">
      stsdjhgfjhgadf
    </div>
  </div>

  content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content
  content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content
  content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content
  content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content
  content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content
  content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content
  content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content
  content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content
  content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content
  content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content
  content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content
  content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content
  content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content
  content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content
  content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content
  content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content
  content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content
  content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content
  content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content
  content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content
  content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content
  content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content
  content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content
  content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content
  content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content
  content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content
  content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content
  content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content
  content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content
  content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content
  content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content
  content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content
  content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content
  content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content
  content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content
  content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content
  content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content
  content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content
  content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content
  content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content
  content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content
  content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[As explained in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26386038/why-does-perspective-changes-fixed-position-in-css),

> `perspective` establishes a containing block similar to the way `position: relative` does.

So your fixed div is getting fixed relative to `#navbar_wrapper`, instead of relative to the window.

The solution is to move `#product_basket` outside `#navbar_wrapper`, as so:

```css
#navbar_wrapper {
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
  perspective: 1500px;
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  padding: 50px 0 0 0;
  min-height: 100%;
}

#product_basket {
  position: fixed;
  max-width: 20%;
  left: 80%;
  top: 60px;
}
```

```html
<div id="product_basket">
  <div id="basket" style="background:red">
    stsdjhgfjhgadf
  </div>
</div>
<div id="navbar_wrapper">
  content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content
  content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content
  content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content
  content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content
  content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content
  content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content
  content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content
  content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content
  content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content
  content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content
  content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content
  content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content
  content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content
  content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content
  content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content
  content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content
  content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content
  content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content
  content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content
  content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content
  content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content
  content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content
  content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content
  content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content
  content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content
  content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content
  content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content
  content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content
  content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content
  content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content
  content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content
  content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content
  content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content
  content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content
  content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content
  content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content
  content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content
  content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content
  content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content
  content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content
  content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content
  content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content
</div>
```