# Parallax + Fixed menu issues

Tags: html, css

I have my navbar who can't stay fixed after putting a parallax effect in CSS.

I put a fixed Navbar on my website with a transition JS "Math.round($(window).scrollTop()) > 490)".

After that I put a parallax for the banner who is just below my navbar.
When I disable the 'perspective: 1px' in the CSS body, my navbar becomes fixed again. If someone can help me , it'll be great ! thanks.

```
body{
    perspective: 1px;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    height: 100%;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden; 
}

.header{
    display: flex;
    position: fixed;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    height: 70px;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 999;
    margin-left:0;
    margin-right:0;
    color: #333333;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    transition: 0.5s ease;

}

.banner{
    margin-top: -20px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    min-height: 40vw;
    padding: 30vw 0 5vw;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-transform-style: inherit;
    transform-style: inherit;
    width: 100vw;
}

.banner, .banner:before{
    background: 50% 50% / cover;
}

.banner::before{
    bottom: 0;
    content: "";
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    background-image: url(/assets/img/bg.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    transform-origin: center center 0;
    transform: translateZ(-1px) scale(2);
    z-index : -1;
    min-height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;

}
```

Comment: Hi, can you add a working fiddle with all: CSS/JS/HTML to your question?

Answer (score 0):

Perspective adds every child to its container block; elements with `position: fixed` are not excluded. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26386038/why-does-perspective-changes-fixed-position-in-css). You are applying perspective to the body element which will affect every element in your page, including the header.

Consider wrapping all of your pages except the header in a div, and applying a perspective to that div instead of the body.

```
<body>
    <header class="header">
    ...
    </header>
    <div class="page-wrap">
        <div class="banner">
        ...
        </div>
    ...
    </div>
</body>
```

with CSS

```
body {
    height: 100%;
}
.page-wrap {
    perspective: 1px;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    height: 100%;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden; 
}
```