# Position fixed not working because of parent

Tags: javascript, css

I am using a CSS Parallax effect on my website. The menu icon has to stay within the parallax container. The parallax container however prevents the menu icon from being fixed positioned.
**Relevant code snippets**

```
<main class="parallax">
  <svg class="ham" viewBox="0 0 100 100" width="60">
    <path ... />
  </svg>
</main>

.parallax {
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  -webkit-perspective: 300px;
  perspective: 300px;

  .ham {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 2vw;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
    transition: transform 400ms;
    user-select: none;
    transform: rotate(90deg);
    cursor: pointer;
    mix-blend-mode: exclusion;
    z-index: 9999;
  }
}
```

Here is a working example: https://jsfiddle.net/ak5j6p9r/

Is there any way I can make the menu icon behave, as if it would be positioned fixed?
I would be very thankful for any kind of help!

Comment: So move it out of `.parallax`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26386038/why-does-perspective-changes-fixed-position-in-css

Comment: if you cannot get the icon outside you have no other way